# Ipad won't mount on Ubuntu 12.04 after updating it to iOS 8

Tags: 12.04, mount, ipad, ios

I just updated my iPad Air to iOS 8. Now it won't mount any more on my computer running Ubuntu 12.04. When I plug it in, it gives me a message that says, "Unable to mount iphone / Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)".

Before the update when I'd mount it, I would see two drives in the file explorer window, "Documents" and "Ipad". The former has the files of all my apps, while the latter has my photos and settings and stuff. Now the "Documents" drive won't mount and I see an unmounted drive icon labled iphone. The Ipad drive mounts as normal. What I need is to get the Documents drive back. My iPad isn't jailbroken.

Until now Ubuntu has allowed me to be a proudly iTunes free iPad user. I'd hate to change that.